# One-liner for calling a function for each line in a file

Tags: python, file-io

I need to keep calling `sync` for each line in `file.txt` until the function returns non-zero(that is when it fails). Currently I plan to do the following.

```
for line in file("file.txt"):
        change=int(line)
        cp_success=sync(change) #check the return value of function sync
        if cp_success!=0 : 
            break               #Try using a break statement
```

Is there a better way or one-liner?

Comment: `goto` statements? REALLY?

Comment: And why a one-liner anyway?

Comment: looks like there is no goto in python...

Comment: This looks like it would go into an infinite loop if there's any line in the file that leads to `cp_success` having the value 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, almost in one line (if you allow me to import the [itertools module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile)):

```
[ x for x in itertools.takewhile(
    lambda line: sync(line) == 0,    # <- predicate
    open("file.txt")) ]              # <- iterable
```

Example w/o file:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> def sync(n):
...   if n == 3: return -1 # error
...   return 0

>>> lines = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> [ x for x in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: sync(x) == 0, lines) ]
[1, 2]
```

But you really should not obscure things, so why not just:

```
with open("file") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if not sync(int(line)) == 0:
            break
```

Answer (score 3):

```
with open(...) as fp: any(sync(line) for line in fp)
```

Comment: @Ignacio - could you explain what all does in the above?how is checking for return value of function "sync"?

Comment: @user1927233: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I understand what your code does. But I'm curious: what thought process brought you to believe this is what the OP wants? I can't confirm/deny that it is what he wants, but I've been unable to answer because his code doesn't "compute" in my head. So I wonder how you arrived at this conclusion (it /does/ seem to help the OP).

Comment: @inspectorG4dget It works because it will short circuit on any non-falsey value from the result of sync for the file...

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: I mostly ignore the code that is in the question since it's usually either badly confused or part of an X-Y problem. I read the description of the problem, and construct the code from that.